# Flutter: SmsAutoFill getAppSignature is null on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, android-studio, flutter

I'm using sms_autofill plugin to get the app signature. When I'm trying to get app signature from android device it got value. While I'm using iOS device it is getting null.

1) Android version getAppSignature is working.

2) iOS version getAppSignature is not working.

`appSignature = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;`

Comment: From the read me - "For iOS, this package is not needed as the SMS autofill is provided by default, but not for Android, that's where this package is useful.".  You don't need this package on iOS and what it does isn't possible on iOS, but iOS provides the functionality as part of the operating system.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's mean only android needed the app signature to use the sms autofill while iOS already provided by default. Thanks for the info it is really helpful.